# An inequality for some series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Consider real positive numbers $t_1,t_2,\ldots, t_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, with $\sum_{i=1}^nt_i^2=n$, such that if  $0<t_i<1$ then $$\frac{t_i}{\sin\left(\dfrac{t_i\pi}{1+t_i}\right)}<1$$ and if $t_i>1$ then
$$\frac{t_i}{\sin\left(\dfrac{t_i\pi}{1+t_i}\right)}<t_i^2.$$
Now can we say that the following inequality hold?
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{t_i}{\sin\left(\dfrac{t_i\pi}{1+t_i}\right)}\le n$$

Comment: Put a sum sign on both sides of the two inequalities?

Comment: No! They don't have sum sign.

Comment: Sum the left and right hand sides of each from 1 to n.

Comment: Any idea, hint?

Answer (score 0):

First inequality: sum on left is what you want, sum on right is < a sum of n 1's i.e n
Second Inequality: Sum on left is what you want, sum on right is a sum of n $t^2$'s, which is n.
you have a less than and a less or equals, so less or equals overall.

Comment: The thing I wanted was this that by using first and second inequality, prove the last one.

Comment: Which is what I did. Write down what I said to do with the sum signs on the first and second inequalities. You now have the result you want. Write it down and look at it.

Comment: You are wrong because if $t_{i_1},t_{i_2},\cdots,t_{i_m}$ be the subsequence of $t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$ which for $t_{i_j}>1$ then we can't say easily $\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i\leq n$. Please read my question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If all $0<t_i<1$ then
$$\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{{{t}_{i}}}{\sin \left( \frac{{{t}_{i}}\pi }{1+{{t}_{i}}} \right)}}<\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}{1}=n.$$

If all $t_i>1$ then $$\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{{{t}_{i}}}{\sin \left( \frac{{{t}_{i}}\pi }{1+{{t}_{i}}} \right)}}<\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}{t_{i}^{2}}=n.$$

If you have a mix of $0<t_i<1$ ($m$ of them, say) and $t_i>1$ ($n-m$ of them) then you have a sum less than $m$ plus a sum less than $n-m$, giving a total sum less than $n$.

Comment: No, for $t_i > 1$, you have $$\frac{t_i}{\sin \left(\frac{t_i\pi}{1+t_i}\right)} > t_i > 1.$$

Comment: OK, see the problem, n is fixed or the conditions can't be consistent.